# how do I move the cursor to the end or beginning of a document using a google script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am fairly new to coding and I am making a script that will move the cursor to and from the end and beginning a a document whenever I type "start 534" or "end 534". My script looks like this:

```
if ('start 534') {

}

if ('end 534') {

}
```

as you can see, I don't have much.

Comment: What type of document ?

Comment: You can go to the end of a document by using the keyboard key combination of CTRL and END.  Hold down the CTRL key, and then while holding down the CTRL key, press END.  CTRL + HOME goes to beginning.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this.  A Google Doc has no way to create an event listener for typing certain characters.  The only event trigger available to a Doc is the `onOpen` event.  You can't monitor for typing certain key strokes.

There are programs that will monitor your keyboard, and run a program from your operating system.

You can add a custom menu item, that would move to the end of the Doc, but you'd need to click on the custom menu, then choose a menu item from a list.